# Disallow object creation for several models

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I am doing a database migration and I need to make sure (temporarily) no new items are created for certain tables.

How would I do the following:

```
class Table1:
    ...

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if not self.pk:
           raise
    super(Table1, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Do the above pattern to these five tables:

```
  - Table1
  - Table2
  - Table3
  - Table4
  - Table5
```

Can I define it in a signal or something else so it's easier to add/remove ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use a signal. For example:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete, pre_save


def block_writes(sender, **kwargs):
    if sender in (Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4, Table5):
        raise Exception("Writes blocked for these tables right now")


# To start blocking
pre_delete.connect(block_writes)
pre_save.connect(block_writes)


# To stop
pre_delete.disconnect(block_writes)
pre_save.disconnect(block_writes)
```

This won't stop *all* writes though, and can't, as they don't all send signals. For example, `Model.objects.update()` will continue to work, as well as raw SQL queries. I'm sure there are other write paths that I've missed too.

Also if you are just trying to stop writes from your web server process whilst the migration process edits the table, you can use a table lock. If you're on MySQL there's a context manager in [`django-mysql`](http://django-mysql.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locks.html#django_mysql.locks.TableLock) for handling these on your models' tables.